# Change case of all text in a column

Tags: google-sheets

How do you change the case to proper case for a whole column in Google Sheets? I don't need it to do anything fancy. I have a header row then 2000 names in a column in various cases. Just need to take the column and make sure it's Proper. But, when I look at the 'help' answers - like if I create a column next to it, I delete the original column and lose all the data.

I just need a *simple way* to make sure the case in the **whole column** is proper.

Also, this simple question is not answered anywhere else that I can locate. I see a bunch of array information, scripts etc -- maybe this can't be done in sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the column with original text is A. In another column, enter

```
=arrayformula(upper(left(A:A, 1)) & lower(right(A:A, len(A:A)-1)))
```

which will create text with first letter in upper case and the rest in lower case.

Then copy that new column and paste it back in A **as values only**. This is done with keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Shift-V, or by right-click and selecting "Paste special - values only".

Answer (score 1):

There is a ChangeCase Add-on by Alec Tutin which seems quite popular and has been assessed quite highly, that will do what you ask and offers various other options also. It does not require a formula or copy/paste.

An alternative formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(lower(A:A),"\b.",upper(left(A:A))))
```